# How to dynamically size an image based upon window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve an effect like the one shown on this website http://seosussex.co.uk/. When the browser window is resized the top image is also resized with it. How can I do this so that the top image is completely in view when a visitor first goes to the website?

The code I have causes the image to be completely resized and it does not fill the window completely.

```
     //Set initial size
     var height =  $(window).height();
     var cHeight = height + "px";
     $('#topImage').css("height",cHeight);

     //Set size on window.resize
     $(window).resize(function(){

        var height =  $(window).height();
        var cHeight = height + "px";
        $('#topImage').css("height",cHeight);

     });
```

Comment: That may have been the slowest website I have ever visited.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly set the width as well as the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually suggest you use the background style with cover.  Otherwise you are going to have a sluggish site like seosussex.

e.g.

```
<style>
    body {
        background: url('image-here') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        display: block;
        ...
    }
</style>
```

ex: [an example](https://www.acornapp.co)

Comment: Be careful kids, if you want to use this with IE8 or worse, you will need to use a polyfill such as https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Answer (score 2):

They are using MaxImage for the full-size bg images.

http://seosussex.co.uk/js/jquery.maximage.js

Here are some notes from the code...

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MaxImage 2.0 (Fullscreen Slideshow for use with jQuery Cycle Plugin)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
This plugin is intended to simplify the creation of fullscreen 
background slideshows.  It is intended to be used alongside the 
jQuery Cycle plugin: 
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

If you simply need a fullscreen background image, please
refer to the following document for ways to do this that
are much more simple:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

If you have any questions please contact Aaron Vanderzwan
at http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/blog/
Documentation at:
http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/

HISTORY:
MaxImage 2.0 is a project first built as jQuery MaxImage Plugin 
(http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/). Once CSS3 came along, 
the background-size:cover solved the problem MaxImage
was intended to solve.  However, fully customizable
fullscreen slideshows is still fairly complex and I have not
found any helpers for integrating with the jQuery Cycle Plugin.
MaxCycle is intended to solve this problem.
*/
```